# Como eu passo o ponto e virgula que fica no final da linha de código HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, linha-de-comando

Estou aprendendo a programar agora. Contudo, estou com um pequeno incomodo em relação ao ponto e virgula no final da linha de código. Quando eu digito a linha de comando uso o autocomplete para me ajudar a completar o comando, entretanto no final da linha de código fica o ponto e virgula e toda vez eu tenho que usar as teclas de cima, baixo, esquerda, direita ou pegar no mouse para descer para próxima linha. Tem algum jeito ou atalho de teclado que possa sanar essa incomodo? Ou algo que eu possa ativar ou criar um atalho de teclado para não precisar usar as teclas, esquerda, direita ou o mouse?

Comment: qual editor você usa? apesar que a sua pergunta não atende os requisitos do site

Comment: Importante você `EDITAR` esta pergunta, explicando-a de forma clara, objetiva e direta, enfatizando a dificuldade encontrada. Além disso, nos forneça um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, junto com sua tentativa de resolução. E mais, sugiro a leitura do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Portugês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor o funcionamento da plataforma e não ter maiores frustrações.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Caso esteja utilizando o VSCode como editor, você pode desativar nas configurações a opção de colocar o ponto e virgula automaticamente. Porém, terás que inserir o ponto e virgula de forma manual. =)

config: Completion: Complete Property With Semicolon